# How to properly check Firebase Auth with Nuxt Middleware?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt app connected with Firebase. I have a composable `useAuth()` with the following code:

```js
import { type User, onAuthChangedListener } from 'firebase/auth';

export default function () {
  const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
  const auth = nuxtApp.$auth; // Auth object from firebase

  const currentUser = useState<User | null>('fbUser', () => auth.currentUser);

  onAuthChangedListener(auth, user => {
    // This console log comes in handy later on...
    console.log("onAuthChangedListener called:", user?.uid);
    currentUser.value = user;
  })

  return {
    currentUser
  }
}
```

And I want to use a Route middleware on some pages to check if the user is authenticated before entered the page.

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  if (!currentUser.value) {
    return navigateTo('/login') // Redirect them to login page.
  }
})
```

And I use this inside `index.vue` with `definePageMeta` to re-route the user accordingly.
When I run my application with `pnpm dev` and visit `/` page, I get redirected to `/login` **even when I am signed in!**

Inside my terminal, I see:

> onAuthChangedListener called: undefined

But on my browser console, I see:

> onAuthChangedListener called: (the logged in user's uid)

Why is there a difference between the server and client here? How do I use middlewares to re-direct them when they actually need to?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a difference between the server and client here?

With Firebase Auth, users don't sign in to backends.  They sign in to frontends.  The user tokens in use are stored only in the web or mobile app.  As such, you can't effectively use the Firebase Auth client SDK on a backend at all. There are no auth state observers or any sense of "current user" on the backend.

Typically if you want to protect a backend from use only by an authenticated user, you have to pass along an ID token from the frontend to the backend in every HTTP request, then verify the token on the backend using the Firebase Admin SDK.  The [Firebase Admin documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) explains the pretty thoroughly with examples.